# Convert Jquery Accordion to Nested Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have used [JQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) to successfully hide elements that can then be opened by clicking on header, but I needed an additional level of nesting - something that Accordion does not support

So Ive been trying to use [Nested Accordion](http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/nested_accordion.html), even without make any other changes just importing the Nested Accordion Javascript completely breaks any nesting or formatting before I even try to add the extra layer of nesting - what am I doing wrong.

Full examples here:

Accordion

http://jthink.net/songkong/scratch/Example1/html/test4.html

Nest Accordion

http://jthink.net/songkong/scratch/Example2/html/test4.html

Comment: Off topic: All your accordion functions can go inside the same script tag and the same document.ready function. Also, if you use a class selector you only need one init function.

Comment: @isherwood thx, only understand your first point though ( i dont usually do javascript)

Comment: Put `class="accordion"` on each and use that in your function: `$('.accordion').accordion();`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say nested accordions aren't supported. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wyuvu9yb

Comment: I didnt think it was, not mentioned anywhere and that seems to be the reason behind Nested Accordian, has it just been added in  JQuery 2 ?

Comment: I think the idea behind Nested Accordion is that you create a nested list structure and initialize the plugin just once. With jQueryUI you'd initialize each level separately.

Comment: I guess either  would work for me, but if you could possibly edit Example1 to show how I can nest the release versions within the '2007 What is the point release' that would be great

Comment: I'd be happy to help if you pull just the relevant code into a http://jsfiddle.net. It's not easy working from a static demo site.

Comment: @isherwood just an update I got it working use standard accordion base don your example, thx.

Comment: Great. Please post an answer below or delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@isherwood was correct that nested accordions are indeed possible with standard accordion